# Xamarin Forms - Muiltiple pages open when label tapped

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm using a couple of labels that when the user taps on one of them it'll open up a new page. But here's the issue, whenever someone taps on one of the labels it'll open up the multiple pages.

I will attach the xaml and code below.

**Xaml**

```
 <StackLayout x:Name="dropdownStack" Padding="10" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="#033c73" IsVisible="False">  
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Image Source="ddm_Home"/>  
      <Label x:Name="ddmenu_Home" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="Home" TextColor="#ffffff"/>
    </StackLayout> 
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Image Source="ddm_Social"/> 
      <Label x:Name="ddmenu_Social" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="Social" TextColor="#ffffff"/>
    </StackLayout>   
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Image Source="ddm_Careers"/>  
      <Label x:Name="ddmenu_Careers" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="Careers" TextColor="#ffffff"/>
    </StackLayout>  
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Image Source="ddm_Schedule"/>
      <Label x:Name="ddmenu_MySchedule" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="My Schedule" TextColor="#ffffff"/>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Image Source="ddm_Contact"/>
      <Label x:Name="ddmenu_Contact" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="Contact" TextColor="#ffffff"/>
    </StackLayout> 
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Image Source="ddm_Details"/>
      <Label x:Name="ddmenu_MyDetails" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="My Details" TextColor="#ffffff"/>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Image Source="ic_video"/>
      <Label x:Name="ddmenu_Videos" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="Videos" TextColor="#ffffff"/>
    </StackLayout>
  </StackLayout>
```

**C#**

```
public void OnDropdownItemPressed()
{
    dropdownStack.IsVisible = !dropdownStack.IsVisible;

    ddmenu_Home.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
    {
        Command = new Command(() =>
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
        })
    });

    ddmenu_Social.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
    {
        Command = new Command(() =>
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new SocialPage());
        })
    });

    ddmenu_Careers.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
    {
        Command = new Command(() =>
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new CareersPage());
        })
    });

    ddmenu_MySchedule.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
    {
        Command = new Command(() =>
        {
            RegisterDeviceWithWebview(ProjectVariables.URL + ProjectVariables.URL_EXT_SCHEDULE, ProjectVariables.regID);
        })
    });

    ddmenu_Contact.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
    {
        Command = new Command(() =>
        {
            RegisterDeviceWithWebview(ProjectVariables.URL + ProjectVariables.URL_EXT_CONTACT, ProjectVariables.regID);
        })
    });

    ddmenu_MyDetails.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
    {
        Command = new Command(() =>
        {
            RegisterDeviceWithWebview(ProjectVariables.URL + ProjectVariables.URL_EXT_DETAILS, ProjectVariables.regID);
        })
    });

    ddmenu_Videos.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
    {
        Command = new Command(() => 
        {
            RegisterDeviceWithWebview(ProjectVariables.URL + ProjectVariables.URL_EXT_VIDEOS, ProjectVariables.regID);
        })
    });
}
```

If someone could help that'd be great.

Comment: What about my suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

I have hypothesis. Each time, when your method `OnDropdownItemPressed` is called you are adding `GestureRecognizers`, so each `Label` has many recognizers instead of one. So, I'd like to suggest to do all `Recognizers` stuff in constructor of a page.

Comment: Vote up as it's maybe the reason

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `VerticalOptions="Fill"` on every `StackLayout` which contains an image and a label. With this option, you tell the `StackLayout` that it should fill the space.

I think this is the problem, that all of your StackLayouts are stacked (and they should not be stacked, just one by one).

Comment: I removed the VerticalOptions="Fill" and its still happening.

Answer (score 1):

**You should disable button or image right after click and wait till page is pushed and then enable it again**

```
ddmenu_Home.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
            {
                Command = new Command(() =>
                {
                    ddmenu_Home.IsEnabled = false;
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
                    ddmenu_Home.IsEnabled = true;
                })
            });
```

Comment: Same thing is still happening, unfortunately.

Comment: Would I need to add the `await` keyword in front of the `Navigation.PushAsync()` even through its not part of an `async` method?

Comment: No, not necessary. Add it and make method async if you think user should wait for this page

Comment: Were you able to fix that issue?

Comment: it doesn't work because after await without wait IsEnabled settled true. awaiter doesn't wait for second  second step...

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below approach.

```
if (Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count == 0 || Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Last().GetType() != typeof(YourPage))
{
    await navigationService.PushTo(new YourPage);
}
```